# kubernetes: apiserver doesn't response to request from inside pods

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have kubernetes(v1.13.4) cluster using Calico(v3.7) as network fabric. The pods related to kubernetes or Calico seem to work fine(and no error logs), so I deployed nginx for test. I throw request from inside nginx pod to apiserver, like `curl https://10.233.0.1/api/v1/node`, but curl doesn't return any response, and finally connection timed out. ping is ok. Requests to Any other service return something(not timeout). I have no idea what should I do next and how can I solve this. Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I flushed my ip tables and ipvsadm, relaunch nginx, and finally the problem resolved. I think my kubernetes inner network was messed.